How do I create and use a clean task in Gulp version 5?
I'm trying to create a clean task in my gulpfile that currently looks like this:
const { series, src, dest } = require('gulp');
const del = import('del');

function clean() {
    del(['node_modules/bootstrap/dist']);
}

function copy(cb) {
    src('node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/*').pipe(dest('wwwroot/lib/bootstrap/dist/css', { overwrite: true }));
    src('node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/*').pipe(dest('wwwroot/lib/bootstrap/dist/js', { overwrite: true }))
    cb();
}

exports.build = copy;
exports.clean = clean;
exports.default = series(clean, copy);

When I run gulp I get this:
PS C:\projects\Mtcsw> gulp
[08:42:56] Using gulpfile C:\projects\Mtcsw\gulpfile.js
[08:42:56] Starting 'default'...
[08:42:56] Starting 'clean'...
[08:42:56] 'clean' errored after 952 μs
[08:42:56] TypeError: del is not a function
    at clean (C:\projects\Mtcsw\gulpfile.js:6:5)
    at bound (node:domain:432:15)
    at runBound (node:domain:443:12)
    at asyncRunner (C:\projects\Mtcsw\node_modules\async-done\index.js:52:18)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:77:11)
[08:42:56] 'default' errored after 3.92 ms

Earlier instead of import('del') I had require('del') and was getting this:
PS C:\projects\Mtcsw> gulp
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module C:\projects\Mtcsw\node_modules\del\index.js from C:\projects\Mtcsw\gulpfile.js not supported.
Instead change the require of index.js in C:\projects\Mtcsw\gulpfile.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\projects\Mtcsw\gulpfile.js:3:13) {
  code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'
}

For reference, the devDependencies of my package.json looks like this:
    "bootstrap": "5.3.3",
    "eslint": "^9.2.0",
    "gulp": "5.0.0",
    "del": "7.1.0"

What's odd to me is that when I look at the example in https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp I was doing what they had shown.  So I'm trying to follow the instructions, but clearly missing something.  What do I need to change?

I think the issue here is that del v7.1.0 uses ES Modules syntax. Every version prior to v7.0.0 used CommonJS which is what Gulp uses to import modules. You simply should not mix ES Modules and CommonJS. Reverting back to del v6.1.1 might solve your problem.
If you prefer to use ES Modules, you can save your gulpfile as 'gulpfile.mjs' and use the relevant statements to make your imports.
This will also affect other modules in your script however. A great deal - if not most - of the modules out there for Gulp are built using CommonJS.
Having said that if you absolutely need to call on modules using both syntaxes, you could use a transpiler like Babel or a bundler like Webpack to ensure compatibility.
